# Hazelcast Backup and restore

Tags: backup, hazelcast, restore, azure-aks

I want to perform Hazel cast back up and restore activity on Kubernetes environment from one AKS cluster to another AKS cluster. If anyone has performed in past or Is there any documentation is available to do that. I just started to learn Hazel cast your support will be appreciable.
I am using Embedded version 4.0.

Answer (score 0):

This feature [hot-backup](https://docs.hazelcast.com/imdg/4.2/storage/hot-restart-persistence.html#hot-backup) does it.

However, this is not avilable in the free edition of Hazelcast.

Comment: any alternative?